Present continuous and continuous infinitive
I'd like to ask about present continuous and continuous infinitive

I'm planning to be working when we are there

I'm planning to be learning all the time


Do 1 and 2 make sense to you? 1 and 2 to emphasize the duration. Does it sound natural or it's just awkward English?

Yes, they could make sense in the right context.  "I'm planning to be working when/while we are there, so I won't have much time to come sightseeing with you."

@KateBunting. What about this one? 1) I'm planning to be working now. Please , if you think it doesn't woro explain why. Thank you in advance.

@Adam - you plan for the future, not the present, so 'now' is wrong.

@MichaelHarvey. What about the same sentence without "now"?

@Adam - planning to be working when? Without that information it is unnatural, unless it is the answer to a question, e.g. 'What are you planning to be doing for the next six months?'.

What is added by "planning", that wouldn't be conveyed by "plan" in those examples?

I'm planning to be working when we are there seems pointlessly complex to me. I can't see any reason why you'd ever want those continuous verb forms, and I suggest it would be better to stick with plain and simple I plan to work when we're there. There might be faint justification for #2 I plan to be learning all the time, but I'm planning... looks clunky in the same sentence as another continuous verb.

If someone is responding to someone, it's entirely usual. "What exactly do you plan to be doing while we're there?" Answer: "I'm planning to be working, that's all, if you really must know". These kinds of questions are not about grammar but about context. You don't use it in the present. plan to be doing something is a future idea.
